# URLEncode Error

Tags: java, android, encoding

I have an Android app. Basically what it does is that user can search a car reference no. in EditText for example:- 270/30 and  retrieve all the details of the particular car with the same column value  in the database. I'm encoding this editext value in Android using URLEncoder and decoding it back in php webservice code. But the decoded value im getting is 027/13 ....instead of 270/30.

To make it clear more im here by pasting   my java Encoding part

```
EditText SearchField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String SearchValue= SearchField.getText().toString();
```

Now the encoding code in Asynctask is

```
data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("data", "UTF-8") + "="+SearchValue;
```

Now the PHP part where i decoded this code

```
$data = urldecode($_POST['data']);
```

Please help me how to encode/decode this given format ...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Correection: value Im getting is not 027/13...it is 027\/13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted code you are only encoding the keyword `data`, not the actual data.

Your PHP decoded side is invalid, because it is decoding something that has not yet been encoded, you need to encode your actual search data like so.

```
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("data=" + SearchValue, "UTF-8");
```

or this, because the keyword `data`, does not need to be encoded.

```
data += "&data=" + URLEncoder(SearchValue, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: With this also im getting the same response...the data im getting in toast when i type 270/10 is like this "027\/13"...I heard from somewhere that "/" wont get encoded in URLEncoder??? not sure

Comment: also even if i type just 3 digit number...for eg:-270...toast is showing output for 270/10 and 270/12 ...which means its taking the first 3 digits....when i type "/" the first three numbers changes...so defo its a problem with taking "/" in URLEncoder...want some help who knows how to set rule for "/" in URLEncoder

Comment: Solved it..Encoding and Decoding was right...it was the problem with my  Sql query .